# prototype function in R

Tags: r, function

I am using notepad++ as my editor for R. One of the difficulties I face is that I don't always remember what the parameter structure looks like for a function I am attempting to call.  Is there a way to have prototypes of the function (like in C++) listed in the .r file?  This way I can see what the call convention is.

Comment: if you vote to close, please comment. your vote to close is not very helpful otherwise

Comment: My advise is to change to RStudio. Its help window is placed very conveniently and user defined functions (including their parameters) are shown in the workspace window.

Comment: Your question is about an general purpose editor, and little to do with R. If you need help on a function usage, look at help `?function_name` or load the `formatR` package and type in `usage(function_name)` to see usage in the console. But still, this has nothing to link R with notepad++

Comment: +1 for Roland. Rstudio will do this for you.

Comment: maybe you want `args(function_name)` or `example(function_name)` as in: `args(lm)` and `example(lm)`

Comment: The R GUI (in OS X at least) will also show you the function+arguments at the bottom margin of the window as you type.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) editor, you may write a function skeleton and define a hot key to insert it into your code. The following is from my emacs help on the hot key (`C-c f`):

> C-c f runs the command R-function-skeleton (found in global-map),
> which is an interactive Lisp function in ‘~/.emacs’.
>
> It is bound to C-c f.
>
> (R-function-skeleton &optional STR ARG)
>
> Insert a R function skeleton

The following is from my emacs customization file (.emacs):

```
(define-skeleton R-function-skeleton
  "Insert a R function skeleton"
  "R Function Name: "
  str " <- function(a, b)\n"
  "{\n"
  "    ## Purpose: \n"
  "    ##   ...\n"
  "    ## \n"
  "    ## Arguments: \n"
  "    ##   - a : \n"
  "    ##   - b : \n"
  "    ## \n"
  "    ## Return: \n"
  "    ##   - y : \n"
  "    ## \n"
  "    ## Author: \n"
  "    ## ________________________________________________\n"
  "\n"
  "\n"
  "}\n"
  "if (F) {                                # Unit Test\n"
  "    " str "(a, b) \n"
  "}\n"
  )
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c f") 'R-function-skeleton)
```

Upon invoking `C-c f` and entering the name of your R function (e.g., `f`), you will see the following function skeleton inserted into the buffer:

```
f <- function(a, b)
{
    ## Purpose: 
    ##   ...
    ## 
    ## Arguments: 
    ##   - a : 
    ##   - b : 
    ## 
    ## Return: 
    ##   - y : 
    ## 
    ## Author: 
    ## ________________________________________________


}
if (F) {                                # Unit Test
    f(a, b) 
}
```